# Accessing Rails Models or Helpers in SCSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails 3.1 and SCSS in the Asset Pipeline. Is there anyway to access Rails helpers or controller data in the SCSS file? Something like...

```
#main {
   background-color: #{current_user.preferences.background_color}
}
```

I know I can set my own `$variables` but I'm not sure how I would populate them from the controller's data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can chain template processors with Rails 3.1, so you can do my.css.scss.erb, and then embed your variables like so:

```
$user-background-color: <%= current_user.preferences.background_color %>
```

Then you can use the Sass variables throughout your SCSS.

I took a different approach to solving this problem for Rails 3.0: [Using SASS with user-specified colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622115/using-sass-with-user-specified-colors)

Comment: Swifty! Is there anything I need to do to make sure that Rails won't try to cache this?

Comment: You probably want some caching to happen, actually. How you go about all of this depends heavily on your environment. On Heroku, for example, you're in a read-only environment, so you can't really cache to disk (except for in `/tmp`).

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar in rails 3.2 but I can't access any controller data with the solution you suggested.  I can make use of rails helpers but can't populate controller data.  How were you able to pass in current_user?

Comment: @Yin If you use `helper_method :current_user` in your controller it'll become available as a helper method in views, and should become available in stylesheets too.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know this is not what Asset Pipeline was designed for.

Think about it, you have a `rake assets:precompile` command to convert all your `.scss.erb` files to a static `.css` file.

So how could you ever possibly access variables like `current_user` from that `.scss.erb` file?

In my opinion, it's not possible to get controller variables in `.scss.erb` or `.coffee.erb`.

Comment: This article helped me out with the process

http://www.krautcomputing.com/blog/2012/03/27/how-to-compile-custom-sass-stylesheets-dynamically-during-runtime/