# Rails 3.2 chain renderers to render a .css.erb.scss view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb, sass

I want to be able to to have a view file called `my.css.erb.scss` in which the `ERB` is handled and then the `SCSS` is compiled.

So for example this file:

```
h1 { color: <%= 'red' %>; }
```

Would result in:

```
h1 { color: red; }
```

Currently the only solution I've found to work is a bit of a fudge and I don't like it (and it's proving difficult to render via this method in specs):

`lib/renders.rb`:

```
ActionController.add_renderer :css do |template,options|
    string = render_to_string template, options
    css = Sass::Engine.new(string, :syntax => :scss).render
    self.content_type ||= Mime::CSS
    self.response_body = css
end
```

Then in the controller I need to do this:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.css { render :css => params[:action] }
end
```

I've tried adding an registering a renderer via the `ActionView::Template::Handler` module method with a `.call` method but I couldn't get the `ERB` to render then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Rails Models or Helpers in SCSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373652/accessing-rails-models-or-helpers-in-scss)

Comment: I've already looked at that. That's talking about rendering via the asset pipeline, I'm talking about adding a view template handler.